# Local variable becomes global after applying function.call()

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Sorry for the title, it is confuse as my ideas about what is going here with the `size` variable:

```
size = undefined
methods = () ->
  this.size = (_) ->
    size = _
    this

lines = () ->
    size = 10 # default value
    x = () -> size
    methods.call(x)
    x

circles = () ->
    size = 15 # default value
    x = () -> size
    methods.call(x)
    x

root.test = {
  lines : lines
  circles : circles
}
```

I wrote the above code in order to define the `size()` method only once, and then adding it to the `lines()` and `circles()` functions.
On the console it seems to work

```
> test.lines()() #10
> test.lines().size(20)() #20
> test.circles()() #15
> test.circles().size(30)() #30
```

The issue appears when the `lines()` and `circles()` functions are called after the `size()` methods have been applied, like the following

```
> var l = test.lines().size(20)
> var r = test.circles().size(30)
> l() # 30
```

On the last line, `l()` returns `30` but I expect `20`.
The `size()` method is able to change the value of the `size` variable appearing in `x = () -> size`, and it changes also its scope, am I wrong?

In other words, can you help me to change the above code in order to have

```
> var l = test.lines().size(20)
> var r = test.circles().size(30)
> l() # 20
```

and keeping the `size()` method definition outside the `lines` and `circles` functions?

Note that `test.lines()` should be a function, not an object.

Comment: No, that `size` method that you create in `methods` is never accessing the any local variables. Those `size` variables in `circles()` or `lines()` are not local either due to coffeescripts scoping rules. It *always* refers to the global variable you've created.

Comment: Ok, this clarifies a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you declared size as global variable, therefore the objects share the same size.

```js
methods = (initial_size) ->
  this._mysize = initial_size
  this.size = (new_size) ->
    if new_size
        this._mysize = new_size
    this._mysize 
  return

l = new methods(10)
r = new methods(30)

console.log(l.size())
console.log(r.size())
```

l is a methods object, which means it has its own _mysize. Same goes for r.
When l.size() is called, it calls the size function with this as l. If new_size parameter is defined, mysize is changed. In any case, mysize is returned.

CoffeeScript also provides the class keyword, which would help you make this code more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was confused by the idea that `size` was local to `lines`. The code you are suggesting helped me, but it does not 100% solve my problem, then I added a note at the very end of my question. I few words, I need to call `l` as a function, the result will depend on `size`, and the `size()` method simply changes the default value of `size`.

Comment: Modify methods to be same as mine, and your code should work. (With a few changes, like calling x.size with the initial size)

Comment: My question has been affected by the erroneous use of the `size` variable. Your first note, as the @Bergi comment, clarified the mistake and I think this this is enough to mark the answer as correct. Then I created a new question, which hopefully is clearer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670514/closures-and-coffeescripts-scoping