# Closures and CoffeeScript's Scoping

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

The following code defines two functions, `lines` and `circles`, that return a function, `f` and `g` respectively. Functions `f` and `g` are equal (`() -> size`) only for simplicity, but in general they are different functions of the variable `size`.

```
lines = () ->
    size = 10 # default value
    f = () -> size
    f.size = (_) ->
      size = _
      f
    f

circles = () ->
    size = 15 # default value
    g = () -> size
    g.size = (_) ->
      size = _
      g
    g
```

On the console, the above code results on the following pattern, which is what I need:

```
> lines()() # 10
> lines().size(20)() # 20
> circles()() # 15
> circles().size(30)() #30
```

As you may note, the `f.size` and `g.size` methods are closures and they are the same on both `lines` and `circles`. Then my question is: *how I can avoid to duplicate the code for the `size` method?* (with coffeescript or javascript)

I tried different solutions, but I did not find the right way. In order to replicate the closure, the `size` variable inside the `size` method should refer to the `size` variable defined at the first line on `lines` (and the same holds for `circles`).

Comment: you can't; method closures to private in-constructor variables must happen in-constructor. if you make `_size` public, you can use prototype methods to reach it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a helper function *in* your code, as that won't have access to the closure variable as expected. However, you can wrap your whole code in a function so that it returns you the `lines` or `circles` function respectively:

```
make = (def, accessor) ->
    () ->
        size = def
        f = () -> accessor size
        f.size = (_) ->
           size = _
           f
        f

lines = make 10, (size) -> size
circles = make 15, (size) -> size
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a factory function to produce your individual "constructors":

```
shape = (defaultSize, calculate = (size) -> size) ->
    () ->
        size = defaultSize
        f = () -> calculate size
        f.size = (_) ->
            size = _
            f
        f

lines = shape(10)

circles = shape(15, (size) -> size * size * Math.PI)
```

This compiles to:

```js
var circles, lines, shape;

shape = function(defaultSize, calculate) {
  if (calculate == null) {
    calculate = function(size) {
      return size;
    };
  }
  return function() {
    var f, size;
    size = defaultSize;
    f = function() {
      return calculate(size);
    };
    f.size = function(_) {
      size = _;
      return f;
    };
    return f;
  };
};

lines = shape(10);

circles = shape(15, function(size) {
  return size * size * Math.PI;
});

console.log(lines()());

console.log(lines().size(20)());

console.log(circles()());

console.log(circles().size(30)());
```

Comment: `lines` and `circles` should be "constructors", each call of them should create its own `size`

Comment: he, now your solution looks just like mine :-) +1